# how to checked checkbox list using database

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have CheckBoxList and want to checked it on edit button. if the column in database has value it will checked otherwise unchecked. checkbox list values are from database.

It show the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

While debugging on:

```
Chk_seat.Items[j].Selected = true;
```

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Chk_seat" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

public void updatefields_seat(long CarID)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
    string qry = @"SELECT [ID]
                ,[ReferenceID]
                ,[CarID]
                ,[Child-Seat]
                ,[Leather-Seat]
                ,[Power-Seat]
                ,[Navigation-System]
                ,[Power-Steering]
                ,[Bucket-Seat]
                ,[IsActive]
                FROM [dbo].[Seat_tbl] Where CarID=" + CarID + "";

    DataSet dsSeat = new DataSet();
    dsSeat = cm.GetQryInDataset(qry);

    if (dsSeat.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dsSeat.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dsSeat.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dsSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Child-Seat"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    Chk_seat.Items[j].Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asif.Ali . Thanks Bro. I Have Solved That issue for after reading your comment. Before i didnt get the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dsSeat.Tables[0].Columns.Count` could be greater than the size/length of your CheckBoxList that's why you are getting this error:

> [Index was out of range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx). Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.